# Change selected tab based on selected radio button and option with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, checkbox, radio-button

I want to achieve the following:

If a country other than Germany (de) is selected from a selection list and the "print" tab is currently selected, the "digital" tab should be selected, the page should be scrolled upwards and an alert box should be displayed.

My code works so far, but the second condition of the second if loop is not evaluated:

```
if (this.value! = 'de' && $("input [value = 'print']"). prop ("checked", true)) {
    ..
}
```

For this reason, every time you select from the selection list, the tab is changed to "digital" and the page scrolls upwards, although it should only be the case with a selected "print" tab.

Here is my complete code:

```
// if a country other than germany is elected, set selected tab to digital and scroll to top
$("select[name='country']").change(function(e){
    $("select[name='country'] option").each(function() {
        if (this.selected) {
            if (this.value != 'de' && $("input[value='print']").prop("checked", true) ) {
                $("input[value='digital']").prop("checked", true);
                $("form .alert").css({display: 'block'});
                var target = $('#top');
                 $('html, body').animate({
                   scrollTop:$(target).offset().top
                 },'slow');
                 e.preventDefault();    
            }                           
        }
    });
});
```

And here is the page with the described tabs and the selection list:

https://www.academyofsports.de/de/anmeldung/fernstudium.html?product=fitness-c-lizenz

---

Updated "solution":

```
// if a country other than germany is elected, set selected tab to digital and scroll to top
$("select[name='country']").on("change", function(e) {
    var isDE = this.value == 'de';
    if (!$("input[value='print']").is(":checked")) 
        return;
        $("form .alert").toggle(!isDE);
    if (isDE) 
        return;
    $("input[value='digital']").prop("checked", true);
    $("input[value='print']").prop( "disabled", true );
    $("select[name='country']").on('change', function() {
        if(isDE){
            $("input[value='print']").prop( "disabled", true );
        }
        else{
            $("input[value='print']").prop( "disabled", false );
        }
    });
    var target = $('#top');
    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: $(target).offset().top
    }, 'slow');
});
```

This way it works now, but if the process repeats, the disable function will not work anymore. Why?

The feature is live now and can be tested here:

https://www.academyofsports.de/de/anmeldung/fernstudium.html?product=fitness-c-lizenz

Comment: Start with `$("select[name='country']").change(function(e){ var val = this.value; `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you mean this?

It is in any case easier to read and modify

```js
$("select[name='country']").on("change", function(e) {
  var isDE = this.value == 'de';
  $("form .alert").toggle(!isDE);
  if (isDE) return;
  if (!$("input[value='print']").is(":checked")) return;
  e.preventDefault(); // Why?
  $("input[value='digital']").prop("checked", true);
  var target = $('#top');
  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $(target).offset().top
  }, 'slow');
});
```

Alternative is

```
$('#top')[0].scrollIntoView();
```

Comment: It works better with your solution. However, I've added something to it and added another feature that disables the tab when a country other than DE is selected. But if I repeat the process a second time, the disable function will not work anymore. Can you tell me why? I have updated my post above and added the current "solution".

Comment: What do you mean by `!isDE && !isDE` that makes no sense!

Comment: Oops, you're right, of course. I forgot to take it out :D

Comment: Also remove the SECOND  `if (!$("input[value='print']").is(":checked")) 
        return;` - it is already executed 3 lines prior

Comment: But it has to be executed at this point but again, otherwise the alert box, even if a different tab than "print" is selected. And as I said the disable function does not work as desired ..

Comment: I cannot help you if you do not get simple Boolean logic. I cannot guess from your code when you want to show an alert if the logic we have does not work

Comment: I removed the second if loop. Works with and without. The problem with the alert box is: 1) I choose the tab "Ausgedruckte Lehrskripte". 2) I select a country other than "Deutschland" in the select box. 3) Page scrolls upwards and alert box is displayed and the tab "Ausgedruckte Lehrskripte" is disabled (everything is fine so far). 4) I switch to "Deutschland" in the select box and the tab is available again. 5) If I select a country other than "Deutschland" in the select box again, everything works up to the disable function of the tab "Ausgedruckte Lehrskripte". Can you understand me?

Comment: I think I cannot reproduce anymore